# VOLTTRON on OS X?

Tags: volttron

Has anyone got VOLTTRON running on OS X?  I'm trying to assess the effort required to make this happen.

It seems that inotify would need to be replaced with something based on FSEvents.  Use of inotify appears to be limited to the `volttron.platform.utils.watch_file` method so it shouldn't be too difficult.

VOLTTRON does start up without error if I comment out the inotify reference but whatever is dependent on `watch_file` is certainly not going to work.   Are there other libraries or behaviors that would be different or unavailable on OS X?  I'm not concerned about hardware/driver interfaces.  I don't intend to deploy on OS X but it would be nice to be able to develop on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up until about two years ago we had a developer who was working in OSX and would kindly point out whenever we broke something in his environment.

We haven't really tried it since.

The two places we watch files is for authorization changes at run time. Those features will still work they just won't update state at runtime.

I don't know of any other libraries we use that would stop you from working in OSX.

Comment: Thanks Kyle.  This is very helpful.  I will see how far I can get on OS X.